# Solved multi-turn simultaneous games

Tags: game-theory, combinatorial-game-theory

It seems that most multi-turn [solved games](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solved_game) are [sequential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_game). Are there (non-trivial) multi-turn [simultaneous games](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simultaneous_game) that are solved?

Comment: I would say the prisoner's dilemma is a pretty thoroughly-analysed simultaneous game.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, that will help me to clarify my question. I am interested in games with several turns, but in which all players chose their next move at the same time. Synchronous chess and Parity chess would be example of such games (but of course I don't think they are solved).
What would be the correct term to clarify my question?

Comment: I'm not that into game thoery, or its vocabulary, so I don't know whether there is a specific word for it.

Comment: The discussion [here](https://cs.stanford.edu/people/eroberts/courses/soco/projects/1998-99/game-theory/Minimax.html) under Matching Pennies seems to be such a game, "solved" by randomization.  If such a game is *not* symmetric, then there may well be a (not interesting) solution where over multiple turns one player has an advantage to exploit.  Matching Pennies shows that in a symmetric game, random choices are better than a "fixed" strategy.

Comment: There is a large literature on repeated games, which somewhat resemble the games that you seem to be trying to describe.

Comment: @hardmath I'm looking for a fearless mathematician to help me analyze [M] games.  Right now I'm trying to gauge the size of the complete gametree, although I've asked only [the easy part of the question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2565921/how-to-determine-the-size-of-the-complete-game-tree-for-basic-m), which can currently be answered without new solutions.  I'm also trying to determine the complexity class--guessing the basic, non-trivial game is harder than NP hard, but I don't know how to go about making that determination.

Comment: typically, "repeated" dilemma is referred to as "iterated dilemma".  The field is still developing, so with [my own project](http://www.fundamentalcombinatronics.com/rules-of-m/), I'm finding I have to coin new terms just to talk about the game, and in some cases, co-opt existing terms such as supersymmetrical (grids) to distinguish between symmetry types of Sudoku variants.  If interested in chatting about this subject, I have an inexhaustible for it, and some grounding in linguistics.  If there's not a current, standard term for the type of games you describe, there needs to be one.